# Css mask shaping & border

Tags: css, css-shapes

I wonder if it is possible for me to do this shape purely with CSS?
[image]

I did try it with image mask but the problem was the border so I went on and try with the background image solution but the problem was the background-size by different devices since there will be text contained inside the box.

I wonder if any has done similar shape or if there are any recommended techniques I need to know, I would be appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working demo of a way you could accomplish this shape with just CSS and no images. I added a pseudo-element and absolute positioned it.

Keep in mind that if your body background is a different color, you'll need to change the color in the `::before` to keep up the illusion.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#box::before {
  background: white;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: @scottymorg Glad I could help. Just so you know, it's customary on Stack Overflow to accept solutions that helped you (with the checkmark icon) to close the question. I see you've asked 29 questions and only closed one.